# Android Studio automatically adjusted contrast now all of my buttons are light, text color changed to black, how to change it back?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio automatically adjusted contrast now all of my buttons are light, text color changed to black, how to change it back?

ALL of my buttons were the default blue and they still show up blue in my xml/design window however when I run the app all the buttons are light grey (I think, I'm colorblind, could be teal), my text has turned to black. At one point AS asked me if I wanted to let it adjust the contrast. Now nothing I change seems to change any button color.

Thoughts?

Comment: buttons of WHAT? Of AS or of the app? Please specify it more clear in your question.

Comment: Any and all the the app Buttons, (Button). The app has them mostly set to setEnabled(false) and then the program decides which one to turn on setEnabled(true), but even my lead in buttons on my front xml have gone to this color scheme, even when enabled. They used to turn blue when enabled. It appears to be app wide. If I try to set a specific button color, it ignores it.